# Fixed point set of torus action is discrete and infinite?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, group-actions

Let $T=(\mathbb{C}^*)^k$ act holomorphically on a smooth quasi-projective complex algebraic variety $M$.

> Can the fixed point set $M^T$ be discrete and infinite?

I think the answer is no because the number of fixed points is equal to the $\chi(M)$, right?

Comment: The Zariski closure of an infinite subset of a smooth quasi-protective complex  algebraic variety has positive dimension. Hence $M^T$ must be at least $1$-dimesnional

Comment: The action is only given as holomorphic, not algebraic, so why should Zariski closure have a useful interaction with the given situation?

Comment: Actually, the action I'm currently looking at is algebraic. However, an answer to my original question (i.e. holomorphic action) is welcome, too.